Where to ask this question about nuclear waste?
I asked a question on sustainability.stackexchange.com, my first one, and there doesn't seem to be much activity on that community.
The question is about managing nuclear waste. Can you recommend a different stack exchange site that is suitable for that question?

While it doesn't answer the [tag:site-recommendation] part, since you have already asked a question which currently has a positive score of one it is probably best to be patient before asking on a different site, since as per the answers to Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site? cross-posting on multiple Stack Exchange site is not generally not well received.

I'd like to point out that you only waited 1 hour and 13 minutes before deciding you weren't going to get an answer on Sustainability.SE and posting this Meta question. That's not a very long time at all. There's no guarantee of an immediate answer on Stack Exchange, even on the more active sites.

@F1Krazy: after those 1 hour and 13 minutes, the question was still at 2 views; Mine and 1 other.

Your first step should be to find if anyone has asked your question before. To do this, you don't necessarily need to start with a given site, just use Google (or your favorite alternative search engine).
A Google search for "stackexchange nuclear waste space" will turn up some existing Q&A that I think likely cover the question you asked or are linked as duplicates to others that will:
Is it possible to send all nuclear waste on Earth to the Sun?
Dispose Earth's nuclear wastes towards the sun
Research/feasibility studies to put the radioactive debris to space, as launch price keeps falling?
